# Modify a repo to get JSON asynchronously

Tags: json, web-services

I'm working on an iPhone app that needs to load data from my server in JSON or XML format. Since the app is free, I get huge amount of data and I get crash when launching app due to the long time when loading the data. So I understand that I should not get "all" the JSON at once but I have to load the data "pagened" [ little by little ] ..

I found this project that suits well my needs but can't get succes to modify it to my need :

https://github.com/nmondollot/NMPaginator

The project tooks Twitter api as a data source, what if I need to deal with a simple php file that returns JSON formatted data?

nb: I tried to contact the project developer after I tried to modify, but didn't get answer until now.

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just load the data asynchrounously instead?

Comment: did you have a sample project or tutorial showing how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution could be to just download the data in another thread. This can be done in many ways but one way to do it is by using grand central dispatch (GCD).

Something like this

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"Your_URL"];
    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:req
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue]
                           completionHandler:
     ^(NSURLResponse *res, NSData *data, NSError *err) {
         // Convert the data to appropriate object
         NSString* myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
//You would probably deserialize the json here
//self.tableViewArray = serialiedObjects;
          
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
             //Reload table view
             [self.tableView reloadData];
         });
     }];
});
```

Comment: ok thanks, please would you explain more, in my project I'm using the data to populate a tableview, suppose that the JSON data is an array of dictionary, each dictionary will be used to one cell in the table view,how can I use your code and reload the tableview as I get new data?